# Select button is hidden in UIImagePicker bar coming form a WKWebView

Tags: swift, ipad, webview, wkwebview, uiimagepicker

I have a WKWebview page in my app which selects an image to upload it so I have NO CONTROL over opening the UIImagePicker It happens natively but the "DONE" button which I can click is not shown in iPad ios 14.7.1 but it's actually clickable!!

[This is how UIImagePicker shown natively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alps7.jpg)

The red area is actually clickable!

I tried changing tint color globally but only the back arrow has changed the button is still hidden or something!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
     open override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.custom
     }
}
```

Try this:

```
 extension UIImagePickerController {
        open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
            self.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.black 
            self.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing has changed I just put this code in the same webview controller. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: try a new one that might be the tint color of barbutton issue

Comment: I did also try the latest one they both run! I can debug them, the back button color can be changed but the right button never appears! even when i change its title